# How to find cells from Column1 that has the specific value from Column2? in python

Tags: python, pandas, list, numpy

I have this CSV file, for example like this table below:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| A | yellow |
| B | green |
| A | blue |

I need a function in python that returns 'yellow' and 'blue' therefore having the same value from column A.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `df.groupby('A').agg({'B': 'unique'})`

Comment: `df[df["Column A"] == "A"]["Column B"]`

Comment: @selin wasd your question answered?